# Updated to 18.04, Broke my PPAs?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa, update-manager

This is the output of `apt-get update` I have no idea what is going on, but I cannot update anymore, any help would be appreciated.

```
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease           
Hit:2 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                  
Hit:3 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                  
Hit:4 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                 
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu bionic 
InRelease          
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Does anybody know why there are 3 downvotes on this new user's post?

Answer (score 1):

No, your PPAs are not broken. It seems the [PPA you're using doesn't have packages published for 18.04](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8). You may be able to change it to an older release, and install packages, but it very possibly won't work or when things do manage to install, they may break.

You should contact the PPA owner and ask them to provide builds for 18.04 now that it is released.